# How can I select the lowest left point in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have some polygons in the same geometry that are separated.

[image]

How can I get the point information of the lowest left corner of each face using geometry nodes?

I'm using Blender 3.

Answer (score 4):

If the polygons are all planes with four vertices...and your geometry nodes tree looks like this, you could e.g. access it like this:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi John, I tried to replicate your node setup but can't find Geometry to instance. I'm getting something like the image: https://ibb.co/ZHYMZPt On concept, Modulo should always return 0? (4 vertices modulo 4 = 0).

Comment: it is in Blender version 3.1